# Decoding json object to get its value not working properly?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am coming to a problem where I am trying to decode the json object to get the value of it but some reason it is still getting my json object which is `{"name": "mike"}`. All I want to achieve is to get the value which is Mike. Is there a work around with my code below. I am using the library called Newtonsoft.Json. Thank you for the help.  *Note that the the json object is coming from a QR code.*

here is my code:

```
    public void CheckUserInDb()
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/QR.json");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";

       using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
      {


         string missingObjectCount = statusText.text;
         dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <dynamic>(missingObjectCount);
         var name = results.ToString();
         streamWriter.Write(name);


   // Another way I tried. 
//          var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(statusText.text);
//            var gettingTheName = result.name;
//             streamWriter.Write(gettingTheName);

      }


       var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.Log(result);
        }

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Verify");

   }
```

Comment: Is the JSON being returned literally just `{"name": "mike"}`?

Comment: yes it is returned as like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had done most of the hardwork. The result.Name is of Type [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm). You only had to take the Value from it using the [JValue.Value](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_Value.htm) property

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(statusText.text);
var gettingTheName = (string)result.name.Value; // Change here
```

Comment: So, First what  do you mean `change here`? and second, I added your code and at the end I added `streamWriter.Write(gettingTheName);`  to write the value to my database later. But, again I see my json object and not the value.

Comment: Well, when I debug `gettingTheName` gets the value but on the front end (unity) side it still shows the object.

Comment: By the change, i meant, use "result.name.Value" instead of "result.name" from your code.

Comment: right. How to fix on the front end (unity) side it shows the json object instead.

Comment: it works. thank you. I have to implement into my QR Code class instead of this class. thanks for kind help @Anu

Answer (score 0):

A safer and more object-oriented way to parse your Json:

```
class JsonObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

...
JsonObject jo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObject>(missingObjectCount);
streamWriter.Write(jo.Name);
```

Comment: So, I create a new class name called `JsonObject` and in another class that I have `CheckUserInDb` method that implement the jsonObject implementation, right?

Comment: Well, the name of the class is not important but it has to correspond to the structure of your Json string. Since your Json string has a name property of type string the class also has a name property of type string. In CheckUserInDb you have to deserialize your json string into an instance of that class as I showed above. Then you can access name property which will contain "mike".